# Bus Error while working on a Two Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void main () {
    int my_data[4][500];

    int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
    int index1 =0;

    my_data[0][1] = 1; 
    my_data[0][3] = 3; 
    my_data[0][5] = 9;
    my_data[0][4] = 10;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(int);i++)
    {   
        if(my_data[0][i] > 0){
            index1 = my_data[0][i];
            myDataBinary[index1] = 1;
            printf("my data %d = %d\n",index1,myDataBinary[index1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The o/p i see is:

```
my data 1 = 1
my data 3 = 1
my data 10 = 1
my data 9 = 1
Bus error
```

I guess this error at the end is because of the sizeof that I use in the "for loop". I want to run my loop only for those values inside my two dimensional aray. Any idea where i am going wrong.

Comment: You actually gave the answer yourself - try using sizeof(my_data[0])/sizeof(int). Or, (in my view) better, use constants for both the array declaration and the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(int);i++)
```

You probably want:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data[0])/sizeof(int); i++)
```

Comment: if i do that then i only get "my data 1 = 1 my data 3 = 1" but not my data 9 and my data 10